# how to write live rescue disc image (ISO) with dd for UEFI boot?

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot, dd, uefi, gpt

How would I prepare [ALT Linux Rescue](https://en.altlinux.org/Rescue) disc to install Linux for dual boot with Windows 10?  Ideally, the USB thumb drive should boot in UEFI mode for a GPT type hdd.  The note on UEFI specifies:

> ↑ with dd(8) or win32diskimager

How would I use dd to write to a USB flash drive so that I don't have to disable secure boot?

Possible answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/395880/45156):

> 1.1. Example via terminal
>
> You can do something like the following if 604A-00EA is your USB drive
>   and you already have p7zip installed:

```
$ 7z x ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso -o/media/$USER/604A-00EA/
```

That's it?  This approach would work for most any live distro?

Comment: The ubuntu iso should be > = `12.04.2` to support the UEFI boot

Answer (score 2):

The ISO must be a hybrid ISO. [Alt Linux is one of them](https://en.altlinux.org/Write)

The stick should be unmounted.

As root:

```
cat /path/to/the.iso >/dev/sdx && sync
```

Replace `sdx` with yours. If you need to use `sudo`, the redirection needs to happen as root:

```
sudo sh -c 'cat /path/to/the.iso >/dev/sdx' && sync
```